# Parceler POJO to Parcelable fails with ParcelerRuntimeException

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

I have a object that contains another object and I'd like to send to from one fragment to another, using parcelable, like:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable(mykey, Parcels.wrap(MySubObj));
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

The structure of the MyObj's POJO:

```
class MyObj {
        String value;
        MySubObj value2;

        //geters & seters

        @Parcel
        class MySubObj {
            String name;
            int age;
            ActivityDomain acdomani;

            //geters & seters

            @Parcel
            public class ActivityDomain {
                String name;
                String field;
                int countEmpl;

                //geters & seters
            }
        }
    }
```

So at `Parcels.wrap(MySubObj)` I am getting this error:

```
org.parceler.ParcelerRuntimeException: Unable to find generated Parcelable class for com.mypakage.MyObj$MySubObj , verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class com.mypakage.MyObj$MySubObj$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.
```

I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The class `com.mypakage.MyObj$MySubObj$$Parcelable` gets auto-generated while building your app. If it's not found, there might be two different reasons for this: It never existed in the first place or was removed in the build by Proguard.

So make sure to configure Proguard correctly

```
# Parcel library
-keep interface org.parceler.Parcel
-keep @org.parceler.Parcel class * { *; }
-keep class **$$Parcelable { *; }
```

And don't forget the dependencies for the annotation processor

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5'
apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
```

Comment: if I ad apt  `org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5 ` I am getting

`Error:(32, 0) Could not find method apt() for arguments [org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`